# Using DownloadManager to download into new folder on phones storage

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, android-download-manager

Im using a download manager which downloads a file into a new folder on the phone storage. Here is the code im using:

```
DownloadManager.Request downloadSample = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urlSample));
downloadSample.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
downloadSample.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Samples/"+previewName, "sample.ttf");
downloadSample.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);    

DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
manager.enqueue(downloadSample);
```

This works perfectly fine on many of the devices Ive tested on, but a few devices force close the app with the following error in the log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(29918): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory: /storage/sdcard0/Samples/Helvetica
E/AndroidRuntime(29918): at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DownloadManager.java:507)
```

Its annoying that it works fine on some but not at all on other devices. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(String dirType, String subPath) says that dirType can take only specified values.

Here dirType can only be the android defined directories for example:

```
Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
```

etc.

you can find all the possible values of dirType at: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)

So the proper way to use this method is:

```
setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, subPath)
```

Also note that this will make the folder in Downloads folder on phone storage. Download manager will not allow you to make a folder in the default directory of phone storage.

This will not give you IllegalStateException for creating directory.